# Вложенные структуры и free.

Tags: c, указатели, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct test_str
{
  struct sub_str_1
  {
    int a;
  } *Sub1;
  strucr sub_str_2
  {
    int a;
  } *Sub2;
} *Test;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Test = malloc(sizeof(struct test_str));
  Test->Sub1 = malloc(sizeof(struct sub_str_1));
  Test->Sub2 = malloc(sizeof(struct sub_str_2));
  /*...any code...*/
}
```

Требуется ли вызывать free для каждой подструктуры, или же достаточно только один раз прописать

```
free(Test);
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, требуется.

Сначала для Test->Sub1 и Test->Sub2, потом для Test.

Comment: @Finn: Добавлю простое правило: каждому `malloc`'у соответствует один вызов `free` (на указатель, возвращённый `malloc`'ом).

Comment: Я бы добавил еще два правила - освобождай только то, что занято (`if (p != NULL){free(p); p = NULL;}`) и освобождай в обратном порядке - то есть в примере это `Test->Sub2`, `Test->Sub1`, а потом `Test`.